# PyQt-Fit's NonParamRegression vs. R's loess

Tags: r, python-3.x, loess

Are those two functions more or less equivalent? For example, if I have an R call like:

```
loess(formula = myformula, data = mydata, span = myspan, degree = 2, normalize = TRUE, family = "gaussian")
```

How can I obtain the same or similar result with PyQt-Fit? Should I simply call the `smooth.NonParamRegression` function (http://pythonhosted.org/PyQt-Fit/NonParam_tut.html) with `method=npr_methods.LocalPolynomialKernel(q=2)`? What about other parameters, such as `span`, and `family`?

**UPDATE**

I do realize the two implementations are likely not equivalent (https://www.statsdirect.com/help/nonparametric_methods/loess.htm). But any comments regarding "approximating" their outcomes are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*Statsmodels* has a LOWESS implementation
(http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess.lowess.html).

Check out this post on the difference between LOESS and LOWESS: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161069/difference-between-loess-and-lowess

**Quick example on how to use *statsmodels'* lowess function in Python**

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

lowess = sm.nonparametric.lowess
```

Generate two random arrays, x and y:

```
x = np.random.rand(100, 1)
y = np.random.rand(100, 1)
```

Run the lowess function (*Frac* refers to *bandwidth*. Note that *frac* and *it* are set arbitrarily. Also, not all parameters are specified here, some are set to default. For more, see the official documentation):

```
results = lowess(y, x, frac=0.05, it=3)
```

The results are stored in a two-dimensional array. The first column contains the sorted x (exog) values and the second column the associated estimated y (endog) values.

If, for instance, you'd like to construct the residuals, you can proceed as follows:

```
res = y - results[:,1]
```